# Vue JS insert and remove html elements dynamicaly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

[image]

I want some thing like this,
If I hit "**Add Another**" button another set of input boxes should render below this set and this set's "**Add Another**" button should change to the "**Remove This School**" and the maximum number of input rows should limited to the 5.

I hope you understand my requirement.What I want is that the user can enter 5 schools or less than 5 schools.If he accidentally add some wrong information he should have a remove button to remove that record.How do I achieve this using Vue JS.
This is my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>Please enter the schools you attained (Maximum five)</p>
    School Name : <input type="text" name="" value="">
    Location  : <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <button type="button" name="button" @click="addAnotherInputBox">Add Another</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      counter:0

    }
  },
  methods:{
    addAnotherInputBox(){

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, although you should have filled the logic of your add button, but you can do that by your own

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sletheren/Lo7t0myL/

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>Please enter the schools you attained (Maximum five)</p>
    School Name : <input v-model="name" type="text" name="" value="">
    Location  : <input v-model="location" type="text" name="" value="">
    <button type="button" name="button" @click="addAnotherInputBox">Add Another</button>
    <ul class="schools">
        <li v-for="school in schools">
            {{school.name}} <button @click="removeSchool(school)">remove</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      counter:0,
      name: '',
      location:'',
      schools: []
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addAnotherInputBox(){
        // your logic here...
       if(this.counter>4){
           alert('you should delete one first! only 5 allowed')
       }else{
            const school = {
                name: this.name, //name here
                location: this.location //location here
            }
            this.counter++;
            this.schools.push(school)
            this.name='';
            this.location=''
       }
    },
    removeSchool(school) {
        this.schools.splice(this.schools.indexOf(school),1);
        this.counter--;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot. I highly appreciate your answer. I learnt a lot from this. Thanks again. =)